# Как в c# изменить координаты окна другого процесса?

Tags: c#

Как в c# изменить координаты окна другого процесса?
Если мы знаем либо индификатор этого окна, либо его заголовок

Comment: WinAPI функция - SetWindowPos, не?

Comment: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowPos

Comment: SetWindowPos вроде только с дочерними окнами работает. Окно другого процесса разве сможет передвинуть?